# Elasticx to query ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elixir, elastix

i am using elasticx (an elasticsearch client for Elixir) to query my ES for getting some logs from there, so i did this configurations:

*) mix.exs:

```
{:elastix, "~> 0.9.0"}, {:httpoison, "~> 1.4"}, {:poison, "~> 3.0"}, {:retry, "~> 0.8"}
```

*) myFile.ex:

```
res0 = Elastix.Index.create("http://15.237.40.183:9200", "twitter", %{})
Logger.debug("\n\n---------- res0 = #{inspect(res0)} ")
```

==> i am getting this error:

```
[debug] 
---------- res0 = {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{id: nil, reason: :closed}}
```

can any one give me some ideas about what happen here please ? and where i should normaly specify my username and password for ES ?